# Running complex functions per row

Tags: r

I would like to use complex functions in a nested data frame.

My data looks like this:

```
Name     Date
John     01.01.
Mark     03.09.
Edith    03.04.
Edith    08.08.
Mark     04.01.
Edith    01.03.
John     01.03.
John     01.04.
Mark     02.03.
Edith    04.05.
Edith    07.05.
Mark     04.02.
Edith    09.01.
John     01.09.
```

In a new column Day, For each name, I would like to know the number of days between a given Date row and the earliest date for that person.

So that John will look like:

```
Day
0
..
2
2
..
9
```

I am experimenting with nest(), then running a function with modfiy, but I am very new to R, and it doesn't work I and looks don't really understand what even the problem is.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Using the `dplyr` package we get

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data %>%
mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%m.%d")) %>%
group_by(Name) %>%
mutate(early = min(Date)) %>%
mutate(Day = difftime(Date, early, units = "days"))

data
# # A tibble: 14 x 4
# # Groups:   Name [3]
#    Name  Date       early      Day     
#    <fct> <date>     <date>     <time>  
#  1 John  2019-01-01 2019-01-01   0 days
#  2 Mark  2019-03-09 2019-02-03  34 days
#  3 Edith 2019-03-04 2019-01-03  60 days
#  4 Edith 2019-08-08 2019-01-03 217 days
#  5 Mark  2019-04-01 2019-02-03  57 days
#  6 Edith 2019-01-03 2019-01-03   0 days
#  7 John  2019-01-03 2019-01-01   2 days
#  8 John  2019-01-04 2019-01-01   3 days
#  9 Mark  2019-02-03 2019-02-03   0 days
# 10 Edith 2019-04-05 2019-01-03  92 days
# 11 Edith 2019-07-05 2019-01-03 183 days
# 12 Mark  2019-04-02 2019-02-03  58 days
# 13 Edith 2019-09-01 2019-01-03 241 days
# 14 John  2019-01-09 2019-01-01   8 days
```

Edited as per Cole's recommendations.

Comment: Differences in days should be whole numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it is not clear from your sample data, whether you are using `%d.%m.` or `%m.%d.` format. Please change that in the code if needed.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- read_table(
'name     date
John     01.01.
Mark     03.09.
Edith    03.04.
Edith    08.08.
Mark     04.01.
Edith    01.03.
John     01.03.
John     01.04.
Mark     02.03.
Edith    04.05.
Edith    07.05.
Mark     04.02.
Edith    09.01.
John     01.09.') 

df %>% 
  mutate(date = as_date(date, "%d.%m.")) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(diff_dates = date - min(date))
```

Result:

```r
> df
# A tibble: 14 x 3
   name  date       diff_dates
   <chr> <date>     <drtn>    
 1 John  2019-01-01   0 days  
 2 Mark  2019-09-03 245 days  
 3 Edith 2019-04-03  92 days  
 4 Edith 2019-08-08 219 days  
 5 Mark  2019-01-04   3 days  
 6 Edith 2019-03-01  59 days  
 7 John  2019-03-01  59 days  
 8 John  2019-04-01  90 days  
 9 Mark  2019-03-02  60 days  
10 Edith 2019-05-04 123 days  
11 Edith 2019-05-07 126 days  
12 Mark  2019-02-04  34 days  
13 Edith 2019-01-09   8 days  
14 John  2019-09-01 243 days
```

Comment: This is not the diff between the earliest for each person, right?

Comment: I've edited the post accordingly. Still, I think the solution using `lubridate` is preferable, as it yields whole numbers for the difference variable.